# Why is rails throwing error if I don't execute code on nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to check if a property is nil and if it isn't, get the content

```
tmp[:field] = maybe_nil != nil ? maybe_nil.content : ''
```

If it is nil, display blank string.

Why would I get `undefined method 'content' for nil:NilClass` if I'm checking for nil and skipping the content accessor on purpose? How else would I execute this logic?

Thanks!

Comment: Need to check more code, to see from where the variable is coming. Only this much code not revealing fact.

Comment: try `!maybe_nil.nil? ? maybe_nil.content : ''`

Comment: A stack trace would be helpful.  That would tell us whether, for example, content is just a property in the maybe_nil class, or content is really a method that's doing a lot more interesting stuff.  If the latter, then the `undefined method` error could be coming from deep within that logic, but without a stack trace we can't tell.

Comment: @bekicot !maybe_nil.nil? is a lot of work in ruby, simply checking for maybe_nil works

Comment: @archie good point. I only follow how he write codes and providing alternatives. The error he stated seems unusual.

Comment: Sorry I think there was an error when I replaced maybe_nil with the actual variable. Can't delete this either, thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tmp[:field] = maybe_nil ? maybe_nil.content : ''
```

Answer (score 0):

if `maybe_nil.content` should always return a string I would do as below instead:

```
tmp[:field] = maybe_nil.try(:content).to_s
```

`nil.to_s #=> ""`

Answer (score 0):

Unless something extraordinary is the case, this should work

```
tmp[:field] = maybe_nil.nil? ? "" : maybe_nil.content
```

Answer (score 0):

tmp[:field] = maybe_nil.present? ? maybe_nil.content : ''

Comment: present is also not matching "", [], and {}. Not only nil value.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
 tmp[:field] = maybe_nil.try(:presence).try(:content) || ''
```